# $watch doesn't work if I specify a scope outside the link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started working on an Angular app that uses flot to plot a bunch of data. It worked fine for static data, but once we got the directive wired up to mongo, I had to follow the tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103671/how-to-integrate-flot-with-angularjs) to get it working for updating data. I had a hell of a time for one specific reason:

This is my directive HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="flotChartCtrl">
  <div data-flot-line-chart data-data="revenueData.data" data-options="line1.options" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
.directive("flotLineChart", [
    function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                data: "=",
                options: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                var chart = null;
                // var options = { ... };

                scope.$watch('data', function(data, oldData) {
                    if(!chart) {
                        chart = $.plot(elem, data, options);
                        elem.show();
                    } else {
                        chart.setData(data);
                        chart.setupGrid();
                        chart.draw();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
])
```

As you can see in the html, I'm using the `data-options` attribute to pass the line1.options object into the directive. When I was just using static data and not using `ng-model` or the `$watch` function, this worked and the `scope: { options: "=" }` assignments were correct. However it seems that whenever I set *anything* on the scope outside `link`, it breaks the `$watch`. `$watch` always receives a `data` of undefined... and my scope.options are also undefined. Outside of the `$watch` function `scope.options` is correct, but that doesn't help me much if I can't use them when the data is actually plotted.

I've had to resort to hard coding the options inside `link:` and commenting out the outer scope assignments. I have a bunch of different charts I need to create, all of which look differently. I'd hate to have to hard code different options for EVERY one, but at the moment I don't see any other way to make this work. Is there some way I can access my other data attributes from the HTML inside the `$watch` function without it breaking everything?

Note: I tried `attrs.options`, but that just gives me a "line1.options" string, and not the actual object.

Edit1:

Updated my code per ExpertSystem's suggestions. No longer using `ng-model`.
`scope` is still not available inside $watch:

[image: Proof that scope isn't defined inside $watch]

Comment: Tip for avoiding hard times in the future: RTFM (and make sure you UTFM) :)

Comment: Believe me, I am reading the manual, but I'm not finding the answers I'm necessarily looking for (or if I am finding them, I'm apparently not understanding them). Unfortunately, I'm still having a hard time, so if you've got a solution instead of an obvious comment, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I posted the comment after I posted a solution :)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying attention to the name. Thought that was someone else :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive should look like this:

```
...
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
    data:    '=ngModel',
    options: '='
},
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    ...
    scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        ...
```

<sub>Althouth the use of `ngModel` seems redundant here.</sub>

---

**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/KKdA7/)** demonstrates that `scope` is indeed defined in the `$watch` callback.

Comment: That fixes the problem of using scope.data inside the $watch for me, but `scope` still doesn't exist inside $watch, which means I can't access `scope.options` inside the $watch... which is my major issue.

Comment: `scope` is definitely available inside the `$watch` callback. Please, post you exact code (where `scope` is undefined).

Comment: That's my exact code. It's telling me scope is not defined.

Comment: Stupidly realized that while `scope` may not be available inside `$watch`, variables declared inside the parent link function *are* available, and `scope` is there, so I'm just assigning `var options = scope.options`, and that works inside my `$watch`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the posted code thare still is **not** any reference to `scope`. I am glad you found a workaround, but `scope` is available inside of the `$watch` callback (exaclty because it is defined inside the parent function). Maybe you are using `options`, instead of `scope.options`.

Comment: You're correct, there's not any reference to `scope` in that code, but there has been -- *multiple* times. It's not currently there, because `scope` *is undefined there* and so I had to take it out and use the `options` variable I'd declared inside `link`. The console screenshot that I posted shows that `scope` is undefined. I placed a breakpoint inside `$watch`, and when it was hit, I attempted to reference `scope` from the console, and as you can clearly see, chrome believes that scope is undefined.

Comment: There may be several reasons for that. E.g. you are in the top-frame, but your code may be running in another frame etc. See at the end of my updated answer for a proof that `scope` **is defined inside the `$watch` callback** !!! You are one stubborn fella, aren't you :P

Comment: Sigh. As soon as I put back the reference to `scope.options` inside `$watch`, the debugger no longer thinks `scope` is undefined. Guess I can't trust the debugger anymore. This was driving me crazy because I couldn't see any reason you would be wrong, but then chrome was telling me differently. Thanks again for the help... and I'm obviously not the only stubborn one on this question. ;)

Comment: Actually, it makes sense. It has to do with JS closures and scoping.